# Restkit v0.2 map Set to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, restkit

I have the following json response

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "columns": [
        {
          "datatype": "STRING", 
          "hidden": false, 
          "name": "key1", 
          "position": 0, 
          "title": "barcode", 
          "value": "0000000117"
        }, 
        {
          "datatype": "DATE", 
          "hidden": false, 
          "name": "key2", 
          "position": 1, 
          "title": "order Date", 
          "value": 1307563633000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to map this to a NSDictionary where the "name" variable will be taken as the Key and the rest ("datatype", "hidden"...) would be mapped to a class.

At the moment I map them to a NSSet and in the response I translate them to a NSDictionary.

```
  for (SREntity * restEntity in mappingResult.array) {
            for (SRColumn *column in restEntity.columnsSet) {

                [restEntity.columns setObject:column forKey:column.name];
            }
        }
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to make the mapping directly.

Something similar to:

```
NSDictionary* columns ->

columns.name : columns.key,
columns : columns.value for columns.key
```

Is this somehow possible?